on_schema_change: "sync_all_columns" throws error: invalid column name
In my config for an incremental model in dbt I used the following configs:
{{
    config(
        materialized='incremental',
        on_schema_change= 'sync_all_columns',
    )
}}

DBT Version: 1.7.17
Adapter Used: SQL Server (sqlserver=1.7.4)
I added new columns in my SQL file, that I expected to be added on SQL server during a dbt run or dbt build -s <model_name>
However I get an error:

invalid column name.

I tried using the configuration in dbt project yaml as well as directly in the model.sql configuration. I tried to use append_new_columns as well. I used the SQL code to create a new model to make sure there are no issues with the columns I added in general, that worked.
Using the --debug flag I could not see any attempt to compare and/or alter the schema of the model in my log files.
Is on_schema_change compatible with the sqlserver-adapter? How can I dig deeper into this? Thank you for your help!

Not much to go on here. At a guess probably dbt isn't quoting column names correctly for its T-SQL connector. If you execute SELECT DISTINCT [name] FROM [sys].[columns] ORDER BY [name]; against the database are there any column names that contain characters like   (space), ", ', [ or ]? Alternatively do you have two or more tables with the same names (but different schemas)?
